# Razor MVC model is losing data on Save action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 1 textbox using TextBoxFor which contains the data.

I have an Id for the Model and some other basic data but displayed as labels directly into the View.

When I submit the form only the textbox field has data on the model, everything else is null including the Id.  This means it won't save into the database.

What would cause all the fields to be null apart from the textbox?

Comment: Please post the *minimal* (i.e. not your entire application) code that illustrates the problem. Include your view code as well as the relevant action methods.

Comment: @Bugai, I know its difficult diagnosing the problem without code, but its really quite difficult posting code when you have large pieces of code across 1) the view, 2) the controller, 3) the model and these all contain context which is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Not being able to easily extract the relevant code sounds like a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Your choice of data persistence model is relevant to this post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the way the web works, only form elements are submitted with the form and labels are not form elements.

What commonly happens here is that you:

1. Render a hidden field (`Html.Hidden` / `Html.HiddenFor`) containing the Id along with the text boxes
2. Accept the changes in your controller action (as parameters or an object)
3. Hydrate the instance of the object represented by Id from your repository/database
4. Apply the changes to the hydrated instance
5. Validate the state of the object and update your repository/database (or whatever you were planning on doing with it)

As the posted data class is often "invalid" due to its missing properties (those marked as `[Required]` for example), its very common to make a new class that has only the properties being changed (called a "command model"). This class can have its own validation properties and thus not muck with your form validation.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the clear & concise response. This makes it a lot clearer, there is quite a bit of work to do on my part to remove the webform mentality from my brain!

Answer (score 6):

Only inputs are posted back to the server.  If you want the model populated based on the data on the page, they must be in inputs (or part of the url).  Data in label elements will not be posted to the server with the form (this is standard HTML form behavior). Typically you'd use hidden fields to post back non-editable model data or simply reference the model id and repopulate from the database, updating the editable properties (as below).

Example:

```
 @(using Html.BeginForm( new { id = Model.ID } ))
 {
       <p>
           <label>Fixed Property:</label>
           @Model.SomeFixedProperty
       </p>
       <p>
          @Html.LabelFor( m => m.EditableProperty )
          @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.EditableProperty )
       </p>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo( int id, string editableProperty )
{
    var model = repo.GetById( id );
    model.EditableProperty = editableProperty;
    repo.Save();
    return View( model );
}
```

Comment: Ok but what if you have a whole form which displays 10 labels, and 1 label for editing. How am I supposed to get this data back to the model without everything being reset? Sounds like this is a major problem that ViewState would have resolved?

Comment: @Jon - (1) hidden fields to go along with the label for each thing you need repopulated in the model, (2) use TempData to hold data from the previous request, or (3) include enough information to reformulate the data needed. ViewState actually does (1), though the data is encrypted. You could, if you so chose, replicate this functionality but I wouldn't recommend it.  From what you say, I'd probably choose (3) and include the model id in the url.  Have your controller action take the id and the updated data as parameters.  Retrieve the model from the DB and modify only wnat is needed.

Comment: @Jon - Please look into session state and understand how it scales before you rely on `TempData`, as that's what `TempData` wraps.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @RichardSzalay , one other way would be to mark unchanged properties as not modified.

Lets say you have a model with these properties: Id, Name, Email. And you don't want to change Email.

```
public ActionResult ChangeName([Bind(Include="Id,Name")] User model)
{
    // ...
    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(model).Property(m => m.Email).IsModified = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
    // ...
}
```

The downside is that you may run into validation problems because of the missing fields in the model.